# Bluetooth wireless earbuds disconnecting frequently on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, earbuds

I'm using truly wireless earbuds with my Android and Windows 10 PC.

The earbuds are working absolutely fine with the Android device, but when connected with Windows 10 PC, they disconnect and reconnect frequently and it becomes very annoying.

It wasn't like this before, but after updating my Windows 10, the problem surfaced.
The earbuds are working absolutely fine with Android devices.

What is the problem with Windows 10 here?

Answer (score -1):

If it's working on the Andriod device but not on Windows then I would modify the Power setting for Bluetooth on Windows:

If it is set to allow your computer to turn off the Bluetooth device
to save power, your Bluetooth can keep disconnecting when in a
low-power state. To solve the issue, you need to modify the Bluetooth
Power setting.

- Use Windows Search to search for device manager and then select the
  first search result to open it.
- Unfold the Bluetooth option and then right-click the Bluetooth device
  you want to fix its Bluetooth disconnect issue. Next, select
  Properties.
- Switch to the Power Management Then, uncheck the Allow the computer
  to turn off this device to save power option.
- Click OK to save the change.

[image]

Comment: there's no such tab as "Power Management" in Properties.

Comment: This answer, found on numerous blogs, assumes windows is in a "low-power state" whenever someone asks this question. That is quite a leap.